# Parsing Data in action

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm connecting my app to an API and the action looks like this

```
export function getDayRoutes(date){
const request = api().get(`/rest/routes/${date}`);
let routes = null;

//code here to transform the data 
request.then((response)=>{
  routes = response.data;
});

return {
    type: GET_DAYROUTES,
    payload: routes
}
}
```

What I want to happen is to parse and transform the data that I would receive from the API and send that to the reducer instead of having the raw data.

Is there a way to this instead of doing it in the component with here in the action? or should I jsut move the transforming function to the reducer?

Comment: I don't really get what you are asking. You have `response.data` returned. you can do whatever transformation there and give `payload` the result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible. You should be using [thunk middleware for redux](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk). when you get your response you modify it to feet your needs and then send it to the reducer. Bellow is an example:

```
export function getDayRoutes(date){
    return (dispatch) => {
        fetch('/rest/routes/' + date).then((response)=>{
            routes = response.data;
            dispatch({
                type: GET_DAYROUTES,
                payload: parseResponse(response);
            });
        });
    } 
}

const parseResponse = (response) => {
    //return desired modified response
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're talking about is [asynchronous actions](http://redux.js.org/docs/advanced/AsyncActions.html).

From your example it might look something like this:

```
export function getDayRoutes(date){
  const request = api().get(`/rest/routes/${date}`);
  let routes = null;

  //code here to transform the data 
  return request.then((response)=>{
    routes = response.data;
    return {
      type: GET_DAYROUTES,
      payload: routes
    };
  });
}
```

That's not tested, you'll see in the redux docs how to apply it exactly to your needs.